# What are the key differences between the movie Edge of Tomorrow and the original book?

Tags: book-adaptation, edge-of-tomorrow

Edge of Tomorrow is based on a original Japanese book, [All You Need is Kill](http://www.amazon.co.uk/All-You-Need-Is-Kill/dp/1421527618) (I still think that would also have been a better movie title).

In some of the answers about the movie there are hints about significant differences from the original source. What are those differences?

Comment: Sorry to point it out, but this is a list question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Movie**: Main protagonist's name is Cage
**Book**: Main protagonist's name is Keiji

**Movie**: Mimics are comprised of the Omega and the Alphas
**Book**: Mimics are comprised of the Nexus and Antennae

**Movie**: Killing an Alpha causes the time loop to reset
**Book** : Killing either the Nexus or the Antennae can cause the time loop to reset

**Movie**: Only Cage is a looper, Rita used to be a looper
**Book**: Both Keiji and Rita are loopers

**Movie**: Getting to the Omega and killing it will end the time loop and stop the alien race
**Book**: The Nexus needs to be killed only after all the Antennae have all been killed

**Movie**: The ending of the Movie, Cage kills the Omega, and is reset back to an earlier time, the entire alien race is dead, no one knows that Cage did it, the world goes back to how it was a day prior, Rita is alive, happy ending.
**Book**: In the final time loop, once they have eliminated all the Antennae, Rita attacks Kaji telling him that they have been in the loop so long that they have become like the Antennae, unless one of them dies, killing the Nexus will only cause the loop to reset. Keiji kills Rita and is crowned the Hero Of The War.

Here's a link that describes the movie plot and it's apparent plot-holes in more depth:
[Edge Of Tomorrow Explained](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/edge-of-tomorrow-2014-movie-vs-book-plot-hole-explained/)

Comment: *"[...] unless one of them doesn't die, killing the Nexus will only cause the loop to reset."* That doesn't make any sense. Do you mean *"unless one of them dies"* or so?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why is it enough for one of them to die if **all** Antennae have to die before?

Comment: I can't remember well but it had something to do with whose time loop they were in (Keiji's). One of the theories is that if Rita did end up killing Keiji, then her time loop would have started and she would need to survive that one. Since the time loop they were in is because of an earlier death of Keiji, his survival broke the time loop.

Comment: Mario, re-visited the book. Rita and Keiji are both in loops of their own. Rita is an antenna in Keiji's loop. Keiji is an antenna in Rita's loop. Therefore one of them has to die and the other will break out of their loop.

Comment: @matt_black, did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This website lists [a mere five](http://nerd-base.com/2014/06/10/5-differences-between-edge-of-tomorrow-and-all-you-need-is-kill/), but considering that those five are basically the core of the movie...

> 1. Major Bill Cage and Private Keiji Kiriya are entirely different
> 2. Rita Vrataski from All You Need is Kill would bitch slap Emily Blunt
> 3. The Mimics are much scarier in the movie
> 4. The War, and our world are very different
> 5. The endings are drastically different

There's also:

- [this topic](http://thatwasnotinthebook.com/diff/all-you-need-is-kill-vs-edge-of-tmorrow) on thatwasnotinthebook.com,
- [this question](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-story-differences-between-Edge-of-Tomorrow-2014-film-and-the-book-it-was-based-on-All-You-Need-Is-Kill) on Quora (with numerous differences listed),
- [this blog post](https://comparativegeeks.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/litflix-edge-of-tomorrow-or-all-you-need-is-kill/) on Comparative Geeks,

... and numerous other resources.